# Angular Menu. Unable to pass data to sub-menu-two

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have a Main Menu, Sub Menu One and Sub Menu Two.

When I click on a Main Menu item Sub Menu One is displayed.

When I click on a Sub Menu One item, I would like Sub Menu Two to be displayed. At the moment I cannot do this.

I have finally managed to get Main Menu and Sub Menu One working correctly but I don't know how to integrate Sub Menu Two.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o9an35

When I click on an item within Sub Menu One, I would like relevant Sub Menu Two to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add same Input and output in sub-menu-two

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmyw2q

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I really have been overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check updated url - its working now - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o9an35

direct-access-page.component.html

```
<app-main-menu 
  (changeMainMenu)="changeMainMenu($event)" 
  style="float: left; width: 150px;">
</app-main-menu>
<app-sub-menu-one 
  [menuItems]="mainMenuChildren" 
  (changeSubMenuOne)="changeSubMenuOne($event)"  
  style="float: left; width: 150px;">
</app-sub-menu-one>
<app-sub-menu-two  
  [menuItemsTwo]="subMenuTwoChildren"
  style="float: left; width: 150px;">
</app-sub-menu-two>
</div>
```

direct-access-page.component.ts

```
export class DirectAccessPageComponent implements OnInit {
  //@Input() mainMenuIndex = new EventEmitter()
  public mainMenuChildren: [{}];
  public subMenuTwoChildren: [{}];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  changeMainMenu(children: [{}]) {
    console.log('changeMainMenu', children);
    this.mainMenuChildren = children;
  }

  changeSubMenuOne(children: [{}]) {
    console.log('changeSubMenuOne', children);
    this.subMenuTwoChildren = children;
  }
}
```

sub-menu-two.component.ts

```
export class SubMenuTwoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() menuItemsTwo: [{}];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

sub-menu-two-component.html

```
*ngFor="let item of menuItemsTwo"
```

sub-menu-one.component.html

```
<div  
    class="ax_default t-menu" 
    *ngFor="let item of menuItems" 
    (click)="showSubMenuTwo(item)"
    style="border: 1px green solid">
    <div >
      <p>
        <span>{{ item["name"] }}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Let me know if you need any help.